# SharePoint 2010 - UPSS configuration struck on starting

Tags: configuration, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-userprofile

UPA and UPSS is configured in SP2010 version - 14.0.4762.1000. UPSS got stopped. When i try to start, it struck on starting. I have checked the logs, ILM logs are there and it stopped at configuring certificates. Not proceeding to next steps.

I have checked and the new FIM certificate is created in the system. there are no errors in ULS logs and Event viewer.

The status of the UPSS in services on server is starting and the ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob timer job also is in running state. It just stays that way even after 2 hours. I do not see any errors. How to check further or am i missing something?

[Log file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpZjG.png)

Comment: Finally resolved it, we checked and removed duplicate FIM certificates created under Farm account and FIM services but we missed FIM certificates under Local Computer account. which was causing the issue, there are no errors. After removing the FIM certificates under local computer which had multiple Certificates as we re-created UPSS multiple time for troubleshooting, UPSS created successfully and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was resolved, we checked and removed duplicate FIM certificates created under Farm account and FIM services but we missed FIM certificates under Local Computer account. which was causing the issue, there are no errors. After removing the FIM certificates under local computer which had multiple Certificates as we re-created UPSS multiple time for troubleshooting, UPSS created successfully and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use *PowerShell* to stop this service. and then Start it.

Below is the command,

```
get-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.TypeName -like "*User*"}
```

Then stop the one using the ID,

```
Stop-SPServiceInstance -identity <GUID>
```

Check from *Central Admin* now. it should be `'Stopped'`. Then start it.

Comment: We have tried that too, many times. Still the response is same.